# ENCRYPTED MESSAGE

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers, english

I have been given a code to break, and I did frequency analysis on it, but I cannot go any further due to the fact that I am not clear on where are the spaces between words, so in example I present you guys with one line of the code here:

• – –• •• – • •• – • • – • • –– – –• • – •• • •– • – •• –• – – •• • • – •• – •– – –– – • • – – –– • • •

So given the example, my question would be: how can I tell which are the spaces between words, or if I just assume there are no spaces at all?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the actual puzzle...

Comment: Well I didn't think it'd be necessary, maybe I'm wrong, but what I wanted to know is how to decipher if there are actual spaces through a change, for example if .. means a space in the encrypted message, or if it is not included and there are just no spaces. I can't figure out how to:( and I wouldnt want the person giving me the challenge, knowing I did get help lol

Comment: You just have to "logic" it out, and guess where the spaces would go. It looks like morse code to me, so the first step would be to identify where there *must* be gaps (i.e. where an invalid character exists)

Comment: I think my head exploded twice. You mean logic it out depending on the frequency analysis? I'm fairly new at this ^^''

Comment: For example, there's no such thing as "- - - ." in Morse code, and thus there must be a letter gap *somewhere* in there, i.e. "- / - - ." or "- - / - ." or "- - - ."

Comment: Of course, I'm not 100% sure that this is Morse code, but Morse sounds about right.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Partial.

> The code is valid Morse code when viewed in a different font, so
>  that "——" is separated into two characters:
>
> ```
> • – –• •• – • •• – • • – • • –– – –• • – •• • •– • – •• –• – – ••
>  • • – •• – •– – –– – • • – – –– • • •
> ```
>
> But this decodes to only a few different letters:
>  
>  E T N  I  T E I  T E E T E E M  T N  E T I  E A  E T I  N  T T I  E E
>  T I  T A  T M  T E E T T M  E E E
>  
>  Note: the only spaces (in the posted code) are single spaces so it is
>  not possible to distinguish words, which in Morse code have a slightly
>  longer pause than between letters.